# Format for PIN Code

Tags: nest-api

In developing to the Nest Cloud API I've tested access using my developer pin code. The pin code is alpha-numeric and my question is:

During the authorization with the pin code, is the evaluation case insensitive or sensitive?

I.e. is `33HV7900` the same as `33hv7900`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on experimentation the :pin_code URL parameter in the CURL request below seems to produce an API access token regardless of case:

Request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=:product_id&code=:pin_code&client_secret=:secret&grant_type=authorization_code'
```

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "my_token_here",
  "expires_in": 315360000
}
```

I have obfuscated values in both the Request & Response.